# How private variables are accessible?

Tags: php, abstract-class, visibility, private-members

This is my class

```
abstract class DataStore_Adapter {

    private $id;

    abstract function update();
    abstract function insert();

    function __construct() {
        $this-> id = 3;
    }
    function save() {
        if(! is_null($this->id)) {
            $this->update();
        } else {
            $this->insert();
        }
    }
}

class VS_DataStroe_Adapter extends DataStore_Adapter {

    function __construct() {
        parent:: save();
    }
    function update() {
        echo "successfully updated!";
    }
    function insert() {
        echo "successfully inserted!";
    }
}

$vs_data = new VS_DataStroe_Adapter();
```

Running this code i get the result

> successfully inserted!

and if i remove

> $this-> id = 3;

from the constructor method of DataStore_Adapter and place it inside function save()
it gives me result;

> successfully updated!

I need  a clarification on this behavior. As i have declared $id as a private variable , i know its only can be access through DataStore_Adapter class.  But when i initialize it inside save() method sub-class can access its value..
How this is possible? and why?

Comment: Where is the code displaying that "sub-class can access its value"? In the code you posted, only the class itself accesses its value.

Comment: Only the class itself (i.e. `DataStore_Adapter`) is accessing the private variable in your example? There's no problem with accessing a private member variable inside a member function...

Comment: ok, how come id= null on the example given above? i thought when sub class is accessing this parent class , every time DataStore_Adapter 's constructor is called so id cannot be null.

Comment: But `$this->id` is never null, since you're invoking the parent constructor from the constructor of the child class?

Comment: But then how if(! is_null($this->id)) become false?

Answer (score 2):

Private attribute is accessible only in the scope of the class which declares it. Save() is defined in the parent class (which declares ID) so it can access it.

In other words `private DataStore_Adapter::$id` can be accessed by `DataStore_Adapter::save()` because both are defined in the same class. If you want to share attributes or methods through inheritance you can use `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

when you call parent:: save() you are calling the DataStore_Adapter's save() method,hence the private attribute $id is visible to save() since both belong to the same class

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about private and other keywords [here.](http://www.dreamsoftworks.blogspot.com/)